# How to set a schedule with multiple cron to do one task with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, schedule

Now I have implemented a class of SchedulingConfigurer to implement a dynamic schedule task as follow code.

```
@Component
public class DynamicScheduledTask implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    private static final String DEFAULT_CRON = "* * * * * ?";
    private String cron = DEFAULT_CRON;

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
      taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        //TODO MyTask
      }
    }, new Trigger() {
      @Override
      public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(cron);
        Date nextExecDate = trigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
        return nextExecDate;
      }
    });
    }

    public void setCron(String cron) {
        this.cron = cron;
    }
}
```

But above code only do one task with one cron expression while I need to set a schedule with multiple corn expression to do the one task,what should I do?

Comment: Hi, Any reason why you are not using @Scheduled (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) ?

Comment: Cuz I need to set a time to schedule task when server is running.

Comment: 1. Have you enabled scheduling with @EnableScheduling annotation. 2. If your application is not running then the scheduled tasks will not run anyways. So for your use case you can schedule task using @ Scheduled(cron ="* * * * * ?")

Comment: Yeah, I have done what you said before.And I can understand what you mean, but I need to set a time which is user request from website to schedule at runtime while @Scheduled(cron ="* * * * * ?") is accept a fixed time(a fixed cron expression).Therefore I code as my question, and it's working, but now I have a problem that my code is only accept one corn expression and what I want is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581781/something-about-cron-expression/43581848#43581848 , do you have any solution for this?

Comment: do both the cron expression is coming from a user ? or one cron is coming from the user and you are calculating the other one based on this?

Comment: Thanks a lot first for giving me suggestions.I get time from user request, then I process time to corn expression.And user will request multiply time to server, so I need to set multiply time to the same schedule task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate (bean) class to do your cron Task. I mean put what ever piece of code you have inside run method into another class

```
@Component
public class CronJobTask {

  public void executeCron(){
      System.out.println("Cron triggered");
     //TODO MyTask
  }
}
```

Then create two classes like the one you have above `DynamicScheduledTask1` and `DynamicScheduledTask2`. In both the classes add dependency to CronJobTask

```
@Autowired
  CronJobTask cronJobTask;
```

and from your run method in both the classes just call

```
cronJobtask.executeCron();
```

And lets assume you get the time from the user through a rest call. So in your controller class add dependecies to both DynamicScheduledTasks

```
@Autowired
DynamicScheduledTask1 dynamicScheduledTask1;
@Autowired
DynamicScheduledTask2 dynamicScheduledTask2;
```

So when you get the time from user. calculate the cron times and do

```
dynamicScheduledTask1.setCron("calculated cron 1");
dynamicScheduledTask2.setCron("calculated cron 2");
```

Comment: Thank u, I got what I want finally.