# Something about cron expression

Tags: spring-boot, cron, schedule

Now I have set a schedule task using cron expression.

However I don't know how to write a cron expression to execute the same task at 14:30 and 17:45.

Even I tried to write "0 30,45 14,17 * * ? *", but it is not the result what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the same expression on two separate lines:

0 30 14 * * ? *

0 45 17 * * ? *

Comment: Thanks a lot, thus I should create two triggers to accept this two cron expression?

Comment: Its not possible to create a single cron expression, because there is no specific pattern to the two times you gave